# How to replace all text after last char

Tags: bash

I have an output which is an ip address. I want to change the last number to always be 100.

`192.168.1.30` I want to do a replace to replace last number after the last `.` to be `100` so i am always left with: `192.168.1.100`

How can i accomplish this?

My Output is:

```
echo $(ip route show dev eth0 | grep default | cut -d ' ' -f 3)
```

Im new to bash and found nothing relating to this question.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this work? `echo $(ip route show dev eth0 | grep default%.\d\d).100`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set Input and output field separators as dot. Assign last column to 100.

```
awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."}{$NF=100}1' inputfile
```

Or by `sed` : Using backrefrencing

```
sed -r 's/(^.*)\.(.*)/\1.100/g' inputfile
```

As per OP comment, This can be done using awk alone. No need of `grep` or `cut`.

```
ip route show dev eth0 |awk '/default/{split($3,a,".");gsub(a[4],"100");print $3}'
```

Comment: How can i implement that into my output from: `echo $(ip route show dev eth0 | grep default | cut -d ' ' -f 3)` Thanks!

Comment: do `ip route show dev eth0 | grep default | cut -d ' ' -f 3 |awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."}{$NF=100}1'`

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks a million :)

Comment: I need to wait 9 minutes before accepting but will do once allowed!

Comment: the sed command could be shorter like: `sed 's/[[:digit:]]\+$/100/`